# why this error is occurred ValueError: Unrecognized marker style array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, k-means, scatter-plot

I have a matrix of PSNR data with size `(1300,6)` and I have to cluster them using k-means. for this aim I use the following code:

```
psnr_bitrate=np.vstack([np.loadtxt(path, dtype='float') for path in glob.iglob(r'E:/UGC/*.txt')])
plt.scatter(psnr_bitrate[:,0], psnr_bitrate[:,1],psnr_bitrate[:,2],psnr_bitrate[:,3],psnr_bitrate[:,4],psnr_bitrate[:,5])

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_features = scaler.fit_transform(psnr_bitrate)
kmeans = KMeans(init="random",n_clusters=3,n_init=10,max_iter=300,random_state=42)
kmeans.fit(scaled_features)
y_kmeans = kmeans.predict(scaled_features)
plt.scatter(scaled_features[:, 0], scaled_features[:, 1],scaled_features[:, 2],scaled_features[:, 3], c=y_kmeans, s=50, cmap='viridis')
```

but it produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\markers.py", line 305, in set_marker
    Path(marker)

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 132, in __init__
    cbook._check_shape((None, 2), vertices=vertices)

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 2293, in _check_shape
    f"{k!r} must be {len(target_shape)}D "

ValueError: 'vertices' must be 2D with shape (M, 2). Your input has shape (1301,).


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-c4b025e12a92>", line 2, in <module>
    plt.scatter(psnr_bitrate[:,0], psnr_bitrate[:,1],psnr_bitrate[:,2],psnr_bitrate[:,3],psnr_bitrate[:,4],psnr_bitrate[:,5])

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2879, in scatter
    **({"data": data} if data is not None else {}), **kwargs)

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 1438, in inner
    return func(ax, *map(sanitize_sequence, args), **kwargs)

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 411, in wrapper
    return func(*inner_args, **inner_kwargs)

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 4473, in scatter
    marker_obj = mmarkers.MarkerStyle(marker)

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\markers.py", line 228, in __init__
    self.set_marker(marker)

  File "D:\software\Anaconda3\envs\py37\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\markers.py", line 309, in set_marker
    .format(marker)) from err

ValueError: Unrecognized marker style array([41.331917, 41.412583, 47.879083, ..., 34.668083, 32.594   ,
       34.651417])
```

what is the problem? how do I plot my data? my data has six dimensions. using scatter for plotting this data is wrong?

Comment: What do all the columns in `psnr_bitrate` represent? [`plt.scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html) has a specific signature; you can't just unload all your data like that. From the error it sounds like whatever you passed for the marker argument made it really angry.

Comment: each column shows the PSNR value for a specific bitrate. for example, the first column is PSNR values for bitrate 1000k and so on. so I could not understand what should I do now?